# Unable to open electron app after packaging the app using electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

After building the electron application using electron-builder, I cannot open the application from the dist folder. I did change all my links to use path.join(__dirname, "relative_path/") as what I have seen in some answers here. But I can't open the application even though the packaging process is successful.

[File structure for the electron app project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlron.png)

Here's an image of my `file structure`, and this is the `package.json` file of the project

```json
{
  "name": "my_little_reminder",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "description": "A simple time reminder app",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "build": "electron-builder --dir"
  },
  "author": "Leonlit",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-notifier": ">=8.0.1",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.2.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.9.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3"
  }
}
```

Finally, here's a link to the repository if the information here is not enough, https://github.com/Leonlit/My-Little-Reminder/tree/development

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by adding and using the npm script `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"`.

Then, using `path.join(app.getPath('userData'), '/tasks.db')` instead of `path.join(__dirname, '/tasks.db')` for the sqlite database storage location.

Finally, changed a link in the index file which caused the application to always request for saving a ASAR file on app launch if left unfixed.